# Bigquery CSV load fails with Python API but successful using GUI

Tags: python-2.7, google-bigquery

I am using Python to create a CSV file and load it into the `BigQuery`. However, it fails to load with the following error:

> Error while reading data, error message: CSV table references column
>   position 4, but line starting at position:4137 contains only 2
>   columns.

Configuration I'm using is as follows:

```
job_config = bigquery.LoadJobConfig()
job_config.source_format = bigquery.SourceFormat.CSV
job_config.ignore_unknown_values = False
job_config.autodetect = False
job_config.field_delimiter = '|'
job_config.write_disposition = bigquery.WriteDisposition.WRITE_TRUNCATE
job_config.max_bad_records = 0
job_config.skip_leading_rows = 0
```

Sample record looks like as:

2c|Blackhawk gone wild|That's Just About Right|Good Times & Great Country;2019-01-16 14:22:07

CSV has total 114 records. When I've set job_config.allow_quoted_newlines = True. It loads only 60 lines or number of lines less than 114.

Creating CSV file as follows:

```
f.write((str(callsign).split('_')[0]).lower().encode('utf-8') + '|' + artist.encode('utf-8') + '|' + song_title.encode('utf-8') + '|' + show_title.encode('utf-8') + '|' + str(time_bq).encode('utf-8') + '\n')

def bq_load():
credential_path = "Key.json"
os.environ['GOOGLE_APPLICATION_CREDENTIALS'] = credential_path

bigquery_client = bigquery.Client()
dataset_ref = bigquery_client.dataset('POC')
table_ref = dataset_ref.table('data_poc')
job_config = bigquery.LoadJobConfig()
job_config.source_format = bigquery.SourceFormat.CSV
job_config.ignore_unknown_values = False
job_config.autodetect = False
job_config.field_delimiter = '|'
job_config.allow_quoted_newlines = True
job_config.allow_jagged_rows = True
job_config.write_disposition = bigquery.WriteDisposition.WRITE_TRUNCATE
job_config.max_bad_records = 0
job_config.skip_leading_rows = 0

with open('current_song.csv', 'rb') as source_file:
    job = bigquery_client.load_table_from_file(
        source_file,
        table_ref,
        location='US',  # Must match the destination dataset location.
        job_config=job_config)  # API request

try:
    print job.job_id
    job.result()  # Waits for table load to complete.
    return 'Success'
except Exception as ex:
    logger.error(
        "The following exception occurred in the table load of job - {} {} ".format(ex, format(job.job_id)))
    return 'Failure'
```

Need to load the full contents of CSV into bigquery. Any help in identifying the reason behind this error would be really helpful

Comment: Usually, those problems are data related (This is an option **That's Just About Righ** or this **Good Times & Great** . Can you set your max error to be greater than 0 and see the impact for example: max_bad_records = 10

Comment: Found the issue. I was not closing the file context properly due to which bigquery load is loading the incomplete data. Thanks for all the help!

Comment: Great happy issue was solved. Will be useful to add a comment with how you close the context for other readers

Comment: Closed the file context with the close() method on file object. For Example: f.close()

Answer (score 0):

You are using different delimiters in your input between your BigQuery and Python examples.

Note: Your sample is using pipe delimiters and has semicolons in the fields.

```
2c|Blackhawk gone wild|That's Just About Right|Good Times & Great Country;2019-01-16 14:22:07
```

Your Python code is using semicolon delimiters:

```
job_config.field_delimiter = ';'
```

Your Bigquery is using pipe delimiters:

```
job_config.field_delimiter = '|'
```

Based upon your BigQuery example, change your Python code to match:

```
job_config.field_delimiter = '|'
```

Note: I do not know why you included your first line of code:

```
f.write((str(callsign).split('_')[0]).lower().encode('utf-8') + ';' + artist.encode('utf-8') + ';' + song_title.encode('utf-8') + ';' + show_title.encode('utf-8') + ';' + str(time_bq).encode('utf-8') + '\n')
```

Comment: Ahhh..sorry I uploaded the mismatch data. I'm already using pipe throughout my process.